# How many terms are rational in the binomial expansion of $(x^{1/2}+y^{1/3})^{100}$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, rational-numbers

I replaced $100$ with $n$, and for there to be a rational term, $n$ must be even or a multiple of $3$. There are 50 even numbers between 1 and 100, and 33 multiples of 3. You must subtract the multiples of 6 because they are double counted.
$50+33-16=67$ rational terms. Am I correct?

Comment: Could you clarify your question some more. When you say "rational" term, do you mean something like $x^2y^7$, but not say, $x^3y^{4/3}$?

Comment: @Alex R. There must be no root in the term, and I now realize my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

As $\;\bigl(x^{1/2}+y^{1/3}\bigr)^{100}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{100}\dbinom{100}{k}x^{k/2}y^{(100-k)/3}$, you have to solve the system
$$\begin{cases}k\equiv 0\mod 2\\k\equiv 100\equiv 1\mod 3\end{cases}\quad\text{in natural numbers},$$
i.e. in the arithmetic progression $1+3m$, you have to find the *even* terms less than $100$.